# Android google plus login integration failed

Tags: android, google-plus, google-signin, android-googleapiclient

I am new to Stack overflow and android development.In my app,adding google plus and facebook login integration.I have problem during google plus login.What i am trying is.........
GooglePlusSignInHelper.java

```
  public class GooglePlusSignInHelper {
   private final static String TAG = "GooglePlusSignInHelper";
    public final static int RC_SIGN_IN = 100;
    private static GoogleSignInOptions gso;

    private static GooglePlusSignInHelper sInstance;
    private static String webClientID;
    private GoogleApiClient googleApiClient;
    private Context context;
    private OnGoogleSignInListener loginResultCallback;
    private ResultCallback<Status> logoutResultCallback;

/**
 * This method should be called before calling any instance.
 * This is neccessary to get access token and id of user.
 * @param googleClientId
 */
public static void setClientID(String googleClientId) {
    webClientID = googleClientId;
}

/**
 * Interface to listen the Google login
 */
public interface OnGoogleSignInListener {
    void OnGSignSuccess(GoogleSignInAccount googleSignInAccount, @Nullable Person person);

    void OnGSignError(GoogleSignInResult errorMessage);
}

    public static GooglePlusSignInHelper getInstance() {
        if (sInstance == null) {
            sInstance = new GooglePlusSignInHelper();
        }
        return sInstance;
    }

    private GooglePlusSignInHelper() {
        // Configure sign-in to request the user's ID, email address, and basic
        // profile. ID and basic profile are included in DEFAULT_SIGN_IN.
        gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
                .requestScopes(new Scope(Scopes.PLUS_LOGIN))
                .requestProfile() //for profile related info
                .requestEmail() //for email
                .requestIdToken(webClientID) //for accessToken and id
                .build();
    }

    public void initialize(FragmentActivity activity, OnGoogleSignInListener onGoogleSignInListener)
    {
        loginResultCallback = onGoogleSignInListener;
        context = activity;
        googleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(activity)
                .enableAutoManage(activity /* FragmentActivity */, new GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
                        Log.e(TAG, "onConnectionFailed: " + connectionResult);
                    }
                } /* OnConnectionFailedListener */)
                .addApi(Auth.GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_API, gso)
                .addApi(Plus.API)
                .build();

        googleApiClient.registerConnectionCallbacks(new GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks() {
            @Override
            public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {
                Log.i(TAG, "onConnected");
            }

            @Override
            public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {
                Log.i(TAG, "onConnectionSuspended");
            }
        });

        googleApiClient.registerConnectionFailedListener(new GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
                Log.i(TAG, "onConnectionFailed");
            }
        });
    }

    public boolean isConnected() {
        boolean isConnected = googleApiClient.isConnected();

        Log.i(TAG, "isConnected()" + isConnected);
        return isConnected;
    }

    public void signIn(Activity activity) {
        Intent signInIntent = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInIntent(googleApiClient);
        activity.startActivityForResult(signInIntent, RC_SIGN_IN);
    }

    public void signOut() {
        Auth.GoogleSignInApi.signOut(googleApiClient).setResultCallback(
                new ResultCallback<Status>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResult(Status status) {
                        if (logoutResultCallback != null) {
                            logoutResultCallback.onResult(status);
                        }
                    }
                });
    }

    private void handleSignInResult(GoogleSignInResult result) {
        Log.d(TAG, "handleSignInResult:" + result.isSuccess());
        if (result.isSuccess()) {
            Log.i(TAG, "Signed in");
            // Signed in successfully, show authenticated UI.
            final GoogleSignInAccount acct = result.getSignInAccount();

            //This code is just for getting google plus information like gender, birthday, aboutme etc
            final Person[] person = {null};
            if(acct!=null) {
                Plus.PeopleApi.load(googleApiClient, acct.getId()).setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<People.LoadPeopleResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResult(@NonNull People.LoadPeopleResult loadPeopleResult) {
                        try {
                            person[0] = loadPeopleResult.getPersonBuffer().get(0);
                        }
                        finally {
                            loadPeopleResult.getPersonBuffer().release();
                        }
                        if (loginResultCallback != null) {
                            loginResultCallback.OnGSignSuccess(acct, person[0]);
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        } else {
            Log.i(TAG, "Signed out");

            if (loginResultCallback != null) {
                loginResultCallback.OnGSignError(result);
            }
        }
    }

    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        // Result returned from launching the Intent from GoogleSignInApi.getSignInIntent(...);
        if (requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN) {
            GoogleSignInResult result = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInResultFromIntent(data);
            handleSignInResult(result);
        }
    }

    public void setLogoutResultCallback(ResultCallback<Status> callback) {
        logoutResultCallback = callback;
    }
```

}

MainActivity.java

```
     findViewById(R.id.google).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
           {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                googleApi();
                gSignInHelper.signIn(MainActivity.this);
            }
        });
     void googleApi(){

          GooglePlusSignInHelper.setClientID(GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID);
          gSignInHelper = GooglePlusSignInHelper.getInstance();
          gSignInHelper.initialize(this, this);
      }
       @Override
      protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, 
   Intent 
    data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if(requestCode == GooglePlusSignInHelper.RC_SIGN_IN)
    {
        gSignInHelper.onActivityResult(requestCode,resultCode,data);
    }}
     @Override
public void OnGSignSuccess(GoogleSignInAccount acct, @Nullable Person person) {
    String name = (acct.getDisplayName()==null)?"":acct.getDisplayName();
    String email = acct.getEmail();

    Log.i(TAG, "OnGSignSuccess: IdToken "+ acct.getIdToken());

    if(person!=null) {
        int gender = person.getGender();

        String genderType = "OTHERS";
        if (gender == 0)
            genderType = "MALE";
        else if (gender == 1)
            genderType = "FEMALE";

        Log.i(TAG, "OnGSignSuccess: gender "+ genderType);
    }

    Uri photoUrl = acct.getPhotoUrl();
    String profilePic = "";
    if(photoUrl!=null)
        profilePic = photoUrl.toString();

    String id = acct.getId();
    Log.i(TAG, "OnGSignSuccess: "+ name);
    Log.i(TAG, "OnGSignSuccess: "+ email);
    Log.i(TAG, "OnGSignSuccess: "+ id);

    if(companyCheck == null){
        Intent in =new Intent(MainActivity.this,CompanyActivity.class);
        startActivity(in);
        finish();
    }else{
        Intent in =new Intent(MainActivity.this,SecondActivity.class);
        startActivity(in);
        finish()    }}
@Override
public void OnGSignError(GoogleSignInResult errorMessage) {
    Log.i(TAG, "OnGSignSuccess: "+errorMessage.toString() );
  }
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "google Sigin Failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

}

onGSignError i have Put the Error message in Log and i got this

```
    error:com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignInResult@b81650
```

dependencies()

```
     implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:11.8.0'
     implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-plus:11.8.0'
```

i would make this using reference in youtube they add two dependencies.if i remove one of this i have an compile time error in import class.

```
       import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignInAccount;
       import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignInResult;
       import com.google.android.gms.plus.model.people.Person;
```

Any one kindly help me to out this.

Comment: Is that already the full error message?

Comment: @Nico yeah how to overcome this problem